# Traspose groupby sublevels into columns pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

gp1.groupby(by=['ID', 'CD'])['BALANCE_AM'].sum()

```
ID          CD
4332        5                    0.0
            58                   0.0
            123              22656.0
756423      47              645087.0
            123             227655.0
```

I want to create columns for each type of CD, what is the sum of BALANCE_AM

Desired Output

```
ID          5     58     123       47
4332        0     0      22656.0   NaN
756423      NaN   NaN    227655.0  645087.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) if necessary `ID` in column:

```
df = gp1.groupby(by=['ID', 'CD'])['BALANCE_AM'].sum().unstack().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `pivot_table` instead of `groupby`:

```
gp1.pivot_table(values='BALANCE_AM', index='ID', columns='CD', aggfunc='sum')
```